# Python: UserDict

Tags: python

I was reading "Diving into Python". And I ran into this piece of code:

```
    class UserDict:
        def __init__(self, dict=None):
            self.data = {}
            if dict is not None: self.update(dict)
```

Question: why is it "self.update" instead of "self.data.update"?

Comment: Is that the whole class? Does it have an `.update()` method of its own?

Comment: @kindall: [It does.](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/UserDict.py)

Comment: @stupidguy: please also post *`UserDict.update()`* method in your question, otherwise it's only half a question.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source code of `UserDict` you'll find that the `update` method is defined separately. The `__init__` method just calls its own `update` method, which calls the `update` of the `data` attribute. This makes the code much more modular and maintainable. Also as @Ignacio points out, it will be much easier to any other class that inherit from `UserDict` to extend or override the `update` method easily.

Comment: "modular and maintainable" `dict` already has a perfectly viable `update()` method; defining your own increases modularity at the cost of *reducing* maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

So that children can redefine the update operation easily by replacing the `update()` method.